# zeit/pkg Error! ESOCKETTIMEDOUT

Tags: node.js, zeit-pkg

I'm trying to package my node project with zeit/pkg.After running the command pkg.，I got this error：

```
$ pkg .
```

> pkg@4.3.3
>   Fetching base Node.js binaries to PKG_CACHE_PATH
>
> Error! ESOCKETTIMEDOUT
>   Asset not found by direct link:
>     {"tag":"v2.5","name":"uploaded-v2.5-node-v10.4.1-win-x64"}
>
> Error! ESOCKETTIMEDOUT

Answer (score 0):

update node version for making executable and check firewall also.